# Find Max value from multiple shapefiles

Tags: r, shapefile, rgdal

I have some shapefiles lets assume I have two shapefiles , in shapefiles there are multiple polygons with some values also both shape file is from same location . two polyogons from different shapefile can have different value but they can overlap. I in between those two polygons I want to find max value in it. also I don't want to lose value where I doesn't over lap as it can overlap with something else as well. I want to do this with all polygons using R code. how can I do it?

Comment: Please explain what you mean with "Max value". Polygons are two dimensional sets and thus do not have a "max value". Are you looking for the convex hull? Or a rectangular bounding box?

Comment: max value stands for bigger value in two polygons @cdalitz

Comment: The "bigger value" of two dimensional points sets is not defined. You seem to mean something different.

Comment: @cdalitz yep you are right! i let me tell you again. i have two shapefiles , inside that there are some shapes . those two shapefiles are from same location . those shape inside that shapefile represent some values (hail value in this case) . now that shape get overlaps with other shapefile's shape . now i want to find , bigger value where that shape gets overlap in between two shapefiles .

Comment: Please provide an example as working R code and explain what the expected answer is. You can draw polygons in R with `polygon()`.